# getting weird output from 2 d array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to a fill a small 2 d array with arbitrary values before moving onto a bigger array. However, when I compile and run my program, I get some weird output. It is not perfectly square. if someone could point out what im doing wrong that would be great.

```
void startarray(char (*arr)[10], int y_length, int x_length);
void printarray(char (*arr)[10], int y_length);

int main()
{
     char arr[10][10];
     startarray(arr, 10,10);
     printarray(arr, 10);

     return 0;
}

void startarray(char (*arr)[10], int y_length, int x_length)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i <= y_length; i++)
    {
         for(j = 0; j < x_length; j++)
         {
             arr[i][j] = 'a';
         }//end for
         arr[i][j] = '\0';  
    }//end for
}

void printarray(char (*arr)[10], int y_length)
{
      int i = 0;
      while(i < y_length)
      {
           printf("\n%s", arr[i]);
           i++;
      }//end while
}
```

Comment: Formatting/indentation...   Not as bad as some, but main() is all fu.. funnied up.

Comment: youre joking? theres only 4 lines in main(). plus its a really small program

Comment: From small badly formatted acorns do massively deformed trees grow... Start as you mean to continue. Don't double-space your code: this is not proofreading. Insert blank lines only where you need to indicate something like, a pause for breath. Phew... sigh. As in other spheres, the way you present yourself mirrors the way you think.

Comment: okay next time i will take this into consideration...thanks

Comment: @JohnDoe You don't seem to appreciate that,  since you wrote the code, you already know exactly what is going on before your posted.  SO cohntributors do not and don't have an unlimited amount of time to service your problems.  If you cannot be bothered to format your code in such a way that it can be quickly, and easily, understood by someone seeing it for the first time in an SO post, why would they wast... spend time helping with your issues?

Comment: OH, BTW, that advice took less than my minimum 0.5 day billing floor.  Please let me know where I can send my invoice for €35..   oh wait, sorry - SO provides advice at NO COST TO YOURSELF.  PLEASE HELP US IN FUTURE!

Comment: In startarray, there are two loops. The limits are different - one is < the other is <=. Could be a cause for inequality

Comment: I fixed any formatting issues. Sorry for not doing this earlier. I thought it was formatting correctly to begin with. I was never told that having so many spaces made it harder to read. and @anita2R I already saw the indexing mistake i made. thanks

Comment: There is a double-whammy here. Firstly you have the outer loop `for(i = 0; i <= y_length; i++)` which will write outside the bounds of the array. The inner `j` loop is OK, except when it has completed `arr[i][j] = '\0';` will also write beyond the bounds of *that* dimension.

Comment: `i <= y_length` --> `i < y_length`, `j < x_length` --> `j < x_length-1`

Comment: thank you for your help everyone. it was because i was trying to access beyond the bounds.